# DataGrip ER-diagram does not show edges for relationships

Tags: database, jdbc, erd, datagrip, maxdb

I am using a commercial SAP MaxDB database with a custom .jar-file as a driver for the database. I am also not able to change the database keys as I only have read-only privileges.

I am having trouble to generate an ERD-Diagram for this database using DataGrip. In the generated ERD-Diagram I can see the tables but I cannot see the relations between the tables (the edges/relations).

According to [ER-diagram not displaying relationships in Datagrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506921/er-diagram-not-displaying-relationships-in-datagrip) one possible cause is that foreign keys are not defined for the database. Can there be other issues that prevent a correct generation of the ERD-Diagram? For example wrong configurations of the driver or port?

What reasons can missing edges in an ERD-Diagram generally have?

Comment: Usually, the reason is that foreign keys are missing. Is it the case?

Comment: You are correct, that is the case. Probably there are also other reasons but not in my case. Eventually I ended using https://github.com/tscott0/erviz as this was the fastest possible way for me to generate an ERD-Diagram.